# Difficulty in understanding integrals of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, complex-numbers, self-learning

I understand what integration of real numbers is. I know how the definition of it is made.
I have trouble in understanding how it works for **complex numbers**.

I am referring to the notes here: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/ch4.pdf.

I understand till how the Reimann sum (page 2) is calculated because it is almost the same as reals. There after, I do not understand a thing.

**Please elucidate what it is.**

Comment: Keep what you understand, because that's all you have to know, and try to solve (some of) the exercises.

Comment: @Berci it all seems like a simple extension of real integration. *except that values for sin, cos, log, etc are slightly different when it comes to definite integrals*

Comment: @Berci is right; use the formula for $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_a^bf(\gamma(t))\frac{d\gamma(t)}{dt}dt$ as a *definition* (it is a definition in most of the books on complex analysis, to my knowledge) and try to apply it in the exercises. The next step is to try to understand why is that formula the "right one" (or at least, a meaningful one). I personally understood it after Analysis II, when integrals along curves in real analysis are introduced. If you are interested in this, please let me know. I will try to cook an example.

Comment: @Avitus I am stuck on the example on page 4.3 (refer link). How did they calculate the complex description of $C1$ ???

Comment: @Little Child that example is tricky because there is a strange mixture of real geometry ($y=x^2$) and complex analysis. In the Gauss plane (the horizontal axis gives the real part of the complex numbers, while the vertical axis the imaginary one), the locus of complex points $\gamma_1(t)=t+it^2$ describes a parabola because $Im(\gamma(t))=Re(\gamma(t))^2$, for all $t$. This is the idea behind the parametrization

Comment: @Avitus so always I will use $\gamma(t) = t + it^2$ ??

Comment: @Little Child do you understand the parabola example, now?

Comment: @Avitus it is beginning to make sense. Each contour will have its own value for $\gamma(t)$. For **parabola** $\gamma(t) = t + it^2$, for a **line**, $\gamma(t) = t + it$ where $a <= t <= b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as contours go, a rough (and probably poor) analogy is suppose you want to integrate the height of a hill. You would lay out a tape measure and measure the height at each point as you walk up the hill - except you can walk up the hill in lots of different ways. You can walk up in a straight line from east to west, or maybe a curve from south to northwest, etc. Maybe you only want to walk AROUND the top of the hill. You can think of the complex function that you're integrating as the hill (except it has a complex height instead of a real height), and the line or curve you're integrating along as the path in the complex plane.

You'll get different measurements depending on where the start and end points are, and how well-behaved the curve is. If the curve is very well-behaved, there's a nifty property that it doesn't matter what the curve is, the integral will be the same as long as the start and end are the same. You could start at point $a=1$, head all the way out to point $c=10^{1000}$ then come back to point $b=2$, and as long as your path is continuous, you will get the same answer as if your curve went straight from $a$ to $b$.

From there, you can imagine that for these well-behaved functions, the curve from $a$ to $a$ - a closed path, would be the same as the integral from $a$ to $a$ - 0, and you would be right.

I'm glossing over a lot here, but this is a very high-level view of how you can visualize complex integration.

Answer (score 1):

Some explanations on the examples the OP is interested in, namely those in

http://people.math.gatech.edu/~cain/winter99/ch4.pdf

at pag. 4.3-4.4.

We want to integrate the function $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=(x^2+y)+i(xy)$ along different paths. Using the notation $z=x+iy$, we have

$$f(z)=\operatorname{Re}(z)^2+\operatorname{Im}(z)+i(\operatorname{Re}(z)\operatorname{Im}(z)).$$

Remark: the function $f$ is not differentiable at $z$ because it does not satisy the Cauchy Riemann equations.

- Case 1:   $\gamma_1(t)=t+it^2$, $t\in [0,1]$.

The locus of points described by the  path $t\mapsto \gamma_1(t)$ is a parabola in the complex plane. In fact, by definition

$$\operatorname{Im}(\gamma_1(t))=\operatorname{Re}(\gamma_1(t))^2,$$
 for all $t\in [0,1]$.

- Case 2  $\gamma_2(t)=1+it$, $t\in [0,1]$.
  The locus of points described by the  path $t\mapsto \gamma_2(t)$ is the vertical line connecting the point $\gamma_2(0)=1+i0$ to $\gamma_2(1)=1+i1$ in the complex plane. By definition all points $\gamma_2(t)$ satisfy

$$\operatorname{Re}(\gamma_2(t))=1$$

with $t\in [0,1]$. Their imaginary part $$\operatorname{Im}(\gamma_2(t))=t$$ increases linearly from the minimum $\operatorname{Im}(\gamma_2(0))=0$ to the maximum $\operatorname{Im}(\gamma_2(1))=1$.

- Case 3 Similar to Case 2, with due changes.

EDIT. Extra example for the OP

Let $\gamma(t):=t+i\sqrt{1-t^2}$ for $t\in[0,1]$. As

$$\operatorname{Re}(\gamma(t))^2+\operatorname{Im}(\gamma(t))^2=
t^2+(1-t^2)=1,$$

then the locus of points $\gamma(t)$ in the complex plane is a 1/4 of a circle of radius $1$, with initial point $\gamma(0)=0+i$ and final point  $\gamma(1)=1$ (direction:clockwise).

Let us introduce the simplified notation $x(t):=\operatorname{Re}(\gamma(t))$ and
$y(t):=\operatorname{Im}(\gamma(t))$

If $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)=(x^2+y)+ixy$, then

$$f(\gamma(t)):=u(x(t),y(t))+i v(x(t),v(t))=(x(t)^2+y(t))+ix(t)y(t)=
(t^2+\sqrt{1-t^2})+i t\sqrt{1-t^2}.$$

A comment on terminology. "Locus" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locus_(mathematics))
denotes a set of points satisfying certain conditions. When I write "the locus of points
$\gamma(t)$..." I mean the set of all points in the complex plane which are of the form

$$\gamma(t)=x(t)+iy(t).$$

In other words, here "locus" means the image in the complex plane of the map (called also curve)  $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$.

Comment: The expression $\gamma(t)=...$ changes every time you describe different paths. If you describe a parabola then you have the expression like in $\gamma_1(t)$, if you describe a vertical line then you have another expression, i.e. $\gamma_2(t)$ and so on. Now you are an expert: what is this path in the complex plane:  $\gamma(t)=t+i\sqrt{1-t^2}$, $t\in[0,1]$?

Comment: Ok, working on it. To find $f(\gamma(t))$ I should replace the real and the imaginary parts of $f(x)$ with corresponding real and imaginary parts of $\gamma(t)$, right ? :-) *last question, I promise*

Comment: and not forgetting to replace $y = x^2$ wherever applicable (for a parabola contour)

Comment: Ok, tell me if you get the answer :-) If $\gamma(t)=x(t)+iy(t)$, with $x(t)=\operatorname{Re}(\gamma(t))$ and $y(t)=\operatorname{Im}(\gamma(t))$, then by definition $f(\gamma(t))=u(x(t),y(t))+iv(x(t),v(t))$.

Comment: $f(\gamma(t)) = (t) + i(1-t^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: I edited my answer with an extra example.

Comment: I have never studied locus. I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Gimme an example $f(x)$ and I will integrate it along the parabola and line path